# How to use Django templatetags in Django View...?

Tags: django

Does anyone know how you can use Django's templatetags in view? I want to call {% lorem %} templatetag in Django View. [Link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/webdesign/)

Any idea?

I tried using it like this

```
from django.contrib.webdesign import lorem_ipsum
def myfunction():
    return lorem_ipsum.paragraphs(3)
```

but, I want to actually use lorem function, but it requires two params (parser, token) and i'm not sure what this is..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solution I found.. I should read their code carefully. Thanks guys!

```
lorem_ipsum.paragraphs(3, False) 
lorem_ipsum.words(3, False)
```

Second param decides whether to use common words or not

Answer (score 3):

```
from django.contrib.webdesign.lorem_ipsum import words, paragraphs
def myfunction(type='w',count=1):
    if type == 'w':
        return words(count)
    if type == 'p':
        return paragraphs(count)
```

Comment: But still this does not pick words or paragraphs in random like what lorem templatetags do.

Answer (score 0):

There is no reason to rely on a template tag in the view like this. If you must insist on doing it, open the django code, and look at the definition of the tag.

Comment: I did... but couldn't figure out how to use this "lorem" tag. I tried using "django.contrib.webdesign.lorem_ipsum.paragraphs" function in my view, but this doesn't randomly generate lorems.

Answer (score 0):

You can directly use that Please refer the https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/templates/ link. If you get any error then post that error.

Comment: I know how to use it in template. I'm just going to use it to do some automation in my python script, that's all.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone using Django v1.8+ (including 1.10) `django.contrib.webdesign.lorem_ipsum` was moved to [`django.utils.lorem_ipsum`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/utils/lorem_ipsum.py). Of note, it's an API for internal use and not subject to the deprecation policy.

**Example:**

```
from django.utils import lorem_ipsum
print(lorem_ipsum.sentence())
```